# Parallelizing nested lapply

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-sp, terra

How best can I parallelize this? `year_ras` is a `spatRaster` while `sh_fields_base` is an `sf` object.

```
yearStats <- lapply(year_list, function(year){

    year_ras <- terra::rast(paste0(datadir, "/Mark_", year, "_Slut.tif"))
    
    fields_baseStats <- lapply(nfields_base, function(p){
      
      IMK_polygon <- fields_base$IMK_ID[p]
      sh_fields_base <- subset(fields_base, fields_base$IMK_ID == IMK_polygon)
      
      year_extract <- exactextractr::exact_extract(year_ras, sh_fields_base, fun="majority")
      
      year_extract_df <- data.frame(base_id=IMK_polygon, year_id=year, poly_id=year_extract)
      
      return(year_extract_df)
      
    })
    
    fields_baseStats_df <- purrr::map_df(fields_baseStats, data.frame)
    return(fields_baseStats_df)
    
})
```

Comment: Have a look at the `future.apply` package?